# Is it possible to develop a classic ASP website directly on a webserver with TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, asp-classic, visual-studio-2013

We currently have a very large Classic ASP website that is critical to our business. It is kept in Visual SourceSafe for version control and we have numerous developers who develop the site in Visual Studio 2005. We open the website with VS2005 directly from the Development web server. We can check the files in and out of VSS directly through VS2005 and all changes we make to the asp pages are visible on the development website immediately, without the need to check back in or copy any files.

We would like to move forward with VS2013 and TFS. Our newer websites are all in TFS and we want to standardize.
Is there a way that we can continue developing the website directly on the web server using VS2013 integrated with TFS? I have found number of articles and responses online about TFS and ASP.NET, but since we don't build classic ASP code, these don't seem to help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really your development server is not where you should be doing your development, but on your local desktops, and then deploying to your development server for initial testing.

However with that said, it looks like your working directory in SourceSafe is where you have IIS pointing to on your development server. You can do the same thing with visual studio and TFS. Just have your Visual Studio workspace pointing to the same location, but checking in everything to TFS.

Edit-  the bin directory for a project typically doesn't get checked in to TFS. The developer would have to make sure they build the project every time they wish to view the site on this development server to populate the bin directory.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. With ASP classic we don't have a bin, and there isn't really a "deploy" process, it is just a matter of copying over asp files. If we set the development location as our "workspace", would we be able to check files in and out individually and work in the same workspace?

Comment: The basic thing is the same for .net. You just copy over all the .aspx files and your bin directory to where IIS is looking.

TFS keeps track of workspaces, and generally doesn't let multiple developers use the same location as their workspace. However you can try it and see if it plays nice.

I feel like I do need to say again that the way you're doing this isn't really best practice and is kind of like trying to hammer a square peg into a round hole.

Each developer's environment should be isolated, and then there should be some sort of formal deploy process, either manually or automated.

Comment: I do agree that the arrangement is not ideal. Although neither is having such an important site still being ASP classic. We are hoping to start replacing pieces of the site with ASP.NET over time (following better practices as we go). I do believe that the current method has served us well however. Currently, we check files in and out of VSS, so there is no concern about stepping on each other's toes. We can see who has which file checked out. We never work on the same areas of the site and there is no "building" in asp, so another developer's issues never affect my work.

Comment: For the most part, our "development" is fixing bugs and adding minor enhancements while we make plans to start upgrading the technology.
Regardless, we would like the first step to be getting rid of VSS and VS2005. We were wondering if this was at all possible, or if we had to completely change the way we were working.
Thanks again for your comments AaronS.

Comment: No problem, I hope I was at least able to give a little assistance. Making the move from classic ASP to .net can be a big one if you've never done it before. Having migrated a couple teams from asp to .net, I found it easier to just make the big leap to get everything structured for .net instead of trying to program in .net (and tfs) using classic asp methodologies and then changing everything again later to .net structures. Good luck to you.

Comment: Thanks AaronS. You are correct that this is not the ideal way to do this. We are going to try your suggestion of setting multiple workspaces on the shared location, but if that doesn't work, we will set up IIS locally and use the deploy to push our changes out to the Development server, using more of a .NET process.